# Looking to use preg_replace to remove characters from my strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the right function, just not finding the right regex pattern to remove (ID:999999) from the string. This ID value varies but is all numeric. I like to remove everything including the brackets.

```
$string = "This is the value I would like removed. (ID:17937)";
$string = preg_replace('#(ID:['0-9']?)#si', "", $string);
```

Regex is not more forte! And need help with this one.

Comment: `'0-9'` inside a single quoted string? You have to learn the basics of programming and SO isn't the place to do that (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = preg_replace('# \(ID:[0-9]+\)#si', "", $string);
```

You need to escape the parenthesis using backslashes `\`.
You shouldn't use quotes around the number range.
You should use `+` (one or more) instead of `?` (zero or one).
You can add a space at the start, to avoid having a space at the end of the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP regex is in `/` and not `#`, after that, parentheses are for capture group so you must escape them to match them.

Also to use `preg_replace` replacement you will need to use capture group so in your case `/(\(ID:[0-9]+\))/si` will be the a nice regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0550232b7934e46b380434d7e9efb60075923c8))

```
$string = "This is the value I would like removed. (ID:17937)";
var_export(preg_replace('/ \(ID:\d+\)/',"",$string));

echo "\n\n";

var_export(strstr($string,' (ID:',true));
```

Output: (I used `var_export()` to show that the technique is "clean" and gives no trailing whitespaces)

```
'This is the value I would like removed.'

'This is the value I would like removed.'
```

Some points:

- Regex is a better / more flexible solution if your ID substring can exist anywhere in the string.
- Your regex pattern doesn't need a character class if you use the shorthand range character `\d`.
- Regex *generally speaking* should only be used when standard string function will not suffice or when it is proven to be more efficient for a specific case.
- If your ID substring always occurs at the end of the string, `strstr()` is an elegant/perfect function.
- Both of my methods write a  (space) before `ID` to make the output clean.
- You don't need either `s` or `i` modifiers on your pattern, because `s` only matters if you use a `.` (dot) and your `ID` is probably always uppercase so you don't need a case-insensitive search.